# Implementar autenticação com certificado digital (ICP) no Apache

Tags: apache, autenticação, certificado-digital

Estou tentando implementar no Apache a autenticação através de PKI com certificados digitais armazenados em token/smart card.

Estou utilizando o XAMPP 5.6.8.0-VC11 em um computador com Windows 7.

Seguindo o que descobri pesquisando na internet, descomentei as seguintes configurações do arquivo `httpd-ssl.conf` nas configurações do Apache:

```
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth  10
```

A partir daí, ao acessar https://localhost, o navegador (IE 11, Chrome 43 e FF 38) exibem a tela de seleção do certificado digital (uso um e-CPF no padrão ICP-Brasil, armazenado em token) e solicita a senha.

Após digitar a senha e pressionar <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, o comportamento nos navegadores é o seguinte:

No IE, me é apresentada uma página com a mensagem :

> Esta página não pode ser exibida.

No FF, fica carregando a página indefinidamente.

No Chrome, é exibida a mensagem:

> A autenticação com base no certificado falhou
>   ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT

e clicando em "detalhes" aparece:

> Este servidor exige um certificado de autenticação e não aceitou o
>   que foi enviado pelo navegador. O seu certificado pode ter expirado ou
>   o servidor não confia no emissor dele. Tente novamente com um
>   certificado diferente, se tiver um, ou será preciso obter um
>   certificado válido de outro lugar.

Já testei diversas configurações adicionais que encontrei na internet, mas nada funciona. Também já alterei as Opções da Internet do Windows referentes a SSL e TSL, também se sucesso.

Gostaria de descobrir como implementar a autenticação com certificado digital para um sistema de login mais seguro que esté em desenvolvimento.

Alguém já passou por isso ou sabe como solucionar a questão?

Comment: O seu servidor Apache reconhece o certificado raiz do ICP-Brasil? A princípio você precisa baixar o(s) certificado(s) raiz da ICP-Brasil e configurar seu servidor para aceitar especificamente certificados emitidos por essa CA em particular (caso contrário, como o *webserver* saberia quais certificados são válidos e quais não são?). Não tenho experiência com esse tipo de configuração, mas [essa página](http://wiki.cacert.org/ApacheServerClientCertificateAuthentication) (em inglês) parece dar uns exemplos.

Comment: Achei um script legal que gera o bundle da ICP aqui: https://gist.github.com/skarllot/9663935

Answer (score 3):

Problema resolvido.
A partir do link indicado pelo mgibsonbr cheguei a outros sites e descobri que o que faltava era realmente indicar para o Apache qual a cadeia de certificação aceitável.

Fiz isso criando um arquivo ca-bundle e indiquei o caminho dele na diretiva SSLCACertificateFile em httpd-ssl.conf

Para criar o ca-bundle, baixei toda a cadeia de certificação (no caso da Certisign), abri no Notepad cada um dos arquivos *.cer, copiei o texto e coloquei num arquivo ca-bundle.crt, também no Notepad. O único cuidado, seguindo as orientações obtidas, foi de colocar cada um dos *.cer na ordem reversa da cadeia, ou seja, o *.cer root da ICPBrasil foi o último.

Assim, o navegador passou a aceitar o certificado do cliente (após reiniciar o Apache), porém informou que o certificado do servidor não era confiável (estava usando o certificado padrão do xampp). Para corrigir isto, adicionei o server.crt como certificado confiável na máquina do cliente (o repositório foi o de Autoridades de Certificação Raiz Confiáveis).

Agora a batalha é pegar os dados do certificado do cliente para usar na autenticação.

Comment: Colega, como você passa os dados do certificado do cliente para o servidor de aplicação? Isto é, como a aplicação sabe quem foi autenticado no caso de um e-CNPJ?

Comment: Poderia compartilhar seu ca-bundle com a ordem dos certificados? Estou tentando acertar aqui mas a caixa de seleção não exibe estes certificados apenas um outro certificado que tenho da GlobalSign

Comment: Para ver como pegar os dados da autenticação veja aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/139462/certificado-digital-a3-e-cpf-como-acessar-as-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-com-javascript/194946#194946

Comment: No PHP com Apache2, depois que você conseguiu configurar o certificado certinho para passar pelo Apache2, é possível visualizar todas as chaves do certificado na $_SERVER. No caso, consegui através da chave SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN, que contém RAZAO_SOCIAL_DA_EMPRESA:CNPJ.